# Developing on Windows CE via bluetooth

Tags: visual-studio-2008, bluetooth, windows-ce, development-environment

I was assigned a legacy C# application for MDTs running Windows CE 6.0. When I connect it to my development computer via USB I can run the application just fine, debugger and all, but our application needs the USB port to connect to an external device, so I can't develop the functionality related to interaction with that device while the MDT is connected to my machine via USB.

The device has built-in Bluetooth, so I decided to try and connect it to my machine via Bluetooth. I tried following [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228841%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). I installed Windows Mobile Center(since I'm running Windows 7 and it doesn't support ActiveSync) and managed to find the configurations in my development machine - but not the ones on the MDT!

I tried to find my PC from the MDT via `Control Panel -> Bluetooth Device Settings`, but when I tried to scan I got an error: `Bluetooth hardware error 10050 (controller not present)`.

device has an external Bluetooth software installed, used for communication with a phone, and when I run it it initializes the Bluetooth and I can get the Bluetooth Manager on the device to work and identify my PC 4 times - with 4 different icons. I couldn't divinate what those icons mean, so I tried them all. Each time I managed to connect to my PC, but it only identified the MDT as a headset, not allowing me to manage it's files and connect Visual Studio...

Am I missing something? How can I get the MDT and PC to recognize each other via Bluetooth like they do via USB, allowing me to develop via Bluetooth?

Comment: Is the USB port OTG, or how is it used for both host and client at the same time?  Don't you have Ethernet as an option for debugging?  FWIW, I have never seen anyone ever use Bluetooth as the debugging pipe in my 15 years of doing CE development.  There may be a reason for that.  Not saying it's impossible, but I've never seen it even attempted.

Comment: @ctacke The USB port is not OTG, as the other device it connects to is not really a USB device. We use a miniUSB cable, where the miniUSB plug is plugged to the MDT and the other side is cut open and wired directly into the other device, and they talk via [SLIP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLIP).

Comment: As for using Ethernet - the MDT does not have a RJ port, and it doesn't seem to support WiFi. That leaves us either USB or Bluetooth for connecting to the Ethernet, but USB is already taken and if I manage to connect to Ethernet via Bluetooth I'll have to do it though my computer, so I might as well use Bluetooth directly.